# How can I add a button over a video in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, social-networking

This is my first time working with HTML other than basic websites.

I have a video-based social media app and I want to share posts with a link like instagram for example.
This link will be a website with a video playing in loop until the user clicks a button over the video. Once this button is pressed, another video plays instead.

How do I add the button over the video so when I click on it another video plays?
This is what I have.

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 order-md-2" style="">
                        <img class="mw-100 mt-lg-0 rounded" src="https://profile_picture.jpeg" alt="image" height="110;" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 4px, 0px);">
                        <h3><strong class="">Cute cat</strong></h3>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" viewBox="0 0 100 20" width="100" class="mb-30 svg-secondary"><path d="m0 9h100v2h-100z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                        <p class="mb-30 lead" style="">This is a card trick I learned when I was at Magic School</p>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled padding-x2-list separate-list mb-50">                    
                        </ul>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-warning light" href="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/sampleApp" style=""><span style=""><strong class="">  Get it now</strong></span></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 mr-auto order-md-1 text-center">
                        <div class="content-box d-inline-block">
                            <img class="mw-100 mt-lg-0 rounded" src="https://example000.mp4" alt="image" height="640;" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 4px, 0px);">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I see you are using an `img` tag with a video source. Use a `video` tag instead.

Bootstrap is a tool intended to make your life easier when it comes to developing the UI of a website. Use it when it is useful. For displaying a button over a video, it's more of an overkill than an aid.

Below, you will see HTML and CSS code which display a button over a video. The important thing to know is: when you make an element `position: relative`, all the child elements which are `position: absolute` will be positioned inside the parent element. In the code, we take advantage of this behavior to show `.video-content` over `.video`.

```css
.video-view {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.video-view .video {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.video-view .video-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-view">
  <video class="video"></video>
  <div class="video-content">
    <button>Sample</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `video` HTML tag to insert videos. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video). You can then specify the source of the video with the element `source` inside the element `video`. Set the attribute `src` in `source` to a link of your video and specify its `type`.

To create a custom button, you can create a container which contains both the video and the custom button. The button will be `position`-ed to `absolute` using CSS to make it appear at the right position in the video (adjusted using CSS). Then, attach an event listener on click to the button to change the source of the video.

Here's a very simple working example below. Click the button with `!` on hovering the video to change its source.

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video')
const source = document.querySelector('source')

video.appendChild(source)
video.play()

const changeVideoButton = document.querySelector('#changeVideo')
changeVideo.addEventListener('click', e => {
  video.pause()
  
  source.setAttribute('src', 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4')
  
  video.load()
  video.play()
})
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

video {
  width: 300px;
}

#changeVideo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  /* Additional styles just to increase visual appeal */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFFFFFDD;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  /* End */
}

/* On hovering the video, show the button */
video:hover~#changeVideo {
  opacity: 1;
}

#changeVideo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <video controls autoplay loop>
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div id="changeVideo">!</div>
</div>
```