# Displaying a button over a background video in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I should start by stressing out that I am not a web developer. I'm familiar with it but it is not my profession or hobby. I'm just trying to make a portfolio and I'd rather get my hands dirty than pay someone else to do it.

Now, I'm trying to have a page displaying my hobbies, one of which is gaming. so I have this gaming page in which I have a video set as the page background. I want to have a button or some sort of component or element displayed at the top left corner or as I hover over the top left corner it should appear as some sort of smooth overlay.

Naturally, I took a crack at it and this is as far as I could get. For some reason the button keeps displaying under the background video instead of being contained inside of it on the top left corner.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Gaming.module.css';
import video from '../../assests/images/Phoenix.mp4'

function VideoBackground() {
  return (
    <div className="video-background">
      <video className='video' autoPlay loop style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
        <source src={video} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <div class="video-content">
        <button>Sample</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default VideoBackground;
```

This is the CSS I'm using, according to this [Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60466943/how-can-i-add-a-button-over-a-video-in-html)

```
.video-view {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.video-view .video {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.video-view .video-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

I expected the button to be contained inside of the background video but no matter what I tried it only displays underneath it.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You didn't specify `z-index` in your positioned elements and that could be the problem of your layout issue

Comment: There's a couple issues here. You have `.video-view` as a class name but did you mean `.video-background`? There's no `video-view` class in your component. Also `class="video-content` should be `className` instead of `class`.  Also you say you want your button to be at the top left but why is it `bottom: 0px`? Try `top: 0; left: 0` instead. Also you will need to apply the same positioning to the video or remove the `position: absolute`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this gonna work. setting the container to position relative. and setting the button container to position relative. if the button disappear type try to set the z-index of the button container to a higher value

```html
<div className="video-background" style={{position: "relative"}}>
      <video controls className='video' autoPlay loop style=" width: 100%; height: 100% ">
        <source src="x.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <div class="video-content" style={{position: "absolute";top:"10px";left:"10px"}}>
        <button>Sample</button>
      </div>
</div>
```